# An ExtrudeGeometry of Three.js can be seen when it's behind another extrude geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I created 2 extrude geometries (cubes) side by side, but the cube behind the other can still be seen when rotating the scene camera.

The cube in the front becomes transparent which is supposed to shield the cube behind.

The codes:

```
var renderer, scene, camera;
function init() {
    // renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        canvas: document.getElementById('mainCanvas')
    });
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000); // black
    var gl = renderer.context;
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 4 / 3, -1, 1);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, -500);
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.8);
    camera.add(light);
    scene.add(camera);
    //-------------------------------------
    var extrudeSettings = {
        amount : 50
    };
    // a cube in the scene
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(
            new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(
                new THREE.Shape([
                    new THREE.Vector2(-20, 20),
                    new THREE.Vector2(20, 20),
                    new THREE.Vector2(20, -20),
                    new THREE.Vector2(-20, -20),
                    new THREE.Vector2(-20, 20),
                ]),
                extrudeSettings),
            new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                color:  0xff0000
            })
    );
    var cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(
            new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(
                new THREE.Shape([
                    new THREE.Vector2(-60, 20),
                    new THREE.Vector2(-20, 20),
                    new THREE.Vector2(-20, -20),
                    new THREE.Vector2(-60, -20),
                    new THREE.Vector2(-60, 20),
                ]),
                extrudeSettings
            ),
            new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                color: 0x00ff00
            })
    );
    cube2.position.x = -20;

    scene.add(cube, cube2);

    // render
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    oribitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera);
    oribitControls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); 
    oribitControls.enableDamping = true;
    oribitControls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
    oribitControls.enableZoom = false;
    oribitControls.autoRotate = true;
    oribitControls.autoRotateSpeed = 1.0;
}

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

And jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/maptalks/y29f32za/

Three.js version : r82

Browser : Chrome (latest)

Many many thanks if any one can point out if there is anything I missed.

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/52xf2s92/) example. Did you want to get such result?

Comment: yes, that's it , thanks very much, @prisoner849

Comment: feel free to use it )